# Google App Engine: Issues with Running Laravel 5.6 Project

Tags: php, laravel, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, laravel-5.6

I'm trying to run a cloned Laravel project on Google App Engine, but no matter what route I try to go, I'm always finding myself stuck at one point:

```
laravel/framework v5.6.9 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

Here's what I've tried:

Delete composer.lock file, then running `composer update` or `composer install`, but I got the same error :(

For reference, here is my `composer.json` file:

```
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
        "laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "ext-ds": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "~1.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0",
        "symfony/thanks": "^1.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ],
        "post-deploy-cmd": [
            "chmod -R 755 bootstrap\/cache",
           "php artisan cache:clear"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    }
```

EDIT:
It may be helpful to add my app.yaml file:

```
runtime: php
env: flex

runtime_config:
  document_root: public

# Ensure we skip ".env", which is only for local development
skip_files:
  - .env
env_variables:
  # Put production environment variables here.
  APP_LOG: errorlog
  APP_KEY: 
  STORAGE_DIR: /tmp
```

Answer (score 2):

As the error says, your version of PHP is incompatible with Laravel.

According to your yaml file you are on the flex environment, so GAE should automatically detect your required version based on your composer file. However, GAE requires you to explicitly state the version you need WITHOUT the release version (see here https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/runtime).

So in your composer file change this

```
"php": "^7.1.3",
```

to this

```
"php": "7.2.*",
```

or this

```
"php": "7.1.*",
```

depending on which version of PHP you want to use, then delete your composer.lock file and run `composer update`

Comment: Still the same problem :(

Comment: Or more specifically, "This package requires php 7.2.* but your PHP version (7.0.30) does not satisfy that requirement", is the specific output